# What is veewee waiting for when it's waiting for ssh login?

Tags: centos, virtualbox, vagrant, veewee

When veewee is displaying the following message, `Waiting for ssh login on 127.0.0.1 with user veewee to sshd on port => 7222 to work, timeout=10000 sec` what exactly is it waiting on?

As far as I can tell there is a ssh server on port 7222 on the host that veewee has put up and it's waiting on that. This means that something in the guest is going to connect back to it. However, I can't figure out what that thing might be - and thus I can't debug further.

*Further details*

I'm trying to build a virtualbox image for vagrant with the `CentOS-6.3-x86_64-minimal` template. My steps:

1. `bundle exec veewee vbox define 'ejs-centos6.3-1' 'CentOS-6.3-x86_64-minimal'`
2. `wget http://mirror.symnds.com/distributions/CentOS-vault/6.3/isos/x86_64/CentOS-6.3-x86_64-minimal.iso`
3. `bundle exec veewee vbox build 'ejs-centos6.3-1'`

The CentOS install appeared to run without error but it's stuck waiting for the ssh login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, there's a Ssh server on listening on port 7222, but it's on the guest (VM), not the host.

The host (Veewee) is waiting to connect to it. This SSH service is supposed to become available when the VM install process finishes, that's one of the steps used by Veewee to assume that the setup went fine and that the VM is ready.

If Veewee blocks and never gets this SSH connection, I think there could be multiple reasons:

- VM setup went wrong and something prevents it from finishing successfully. Check Veewee output and the Virtualbox VM graphical console that should have opened when launching `vewee box build`.
- There's something preventing your host computer to connect to the VM at the network level.
- The VM image doesn't have Sshd installed, and/or the veewee box configuration files (in veewee/definitions/ejs-centos6.3-1/) miss instructions to install the ssh package

You should try to login to the VM using Virtuabox console window and check if there's an ssh package installed (`rpm -qa | grep openssh-server`) and a process named `sshd` running.

Answer (score 0):

I've run Veewee against Centos 7 built with GUI on and it stuck on anaconda asking for source of packages. I've checked the ks.cfg and it was pointing to dead resource (404). After pointing to valid url it went through.